# Anyway to run Kinect on virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, kinect, openni

I have installed Windows 7 64 bit on virtual box..
I want to run any driver for kinect on it such as openni, openkinect or kinect sdk
I don't want to run it on native environment..

Is there any way to run kinect on oracle virtual box?

[update]
I have done this by installing openni
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ZIr.png

but kinect still doesn't work

Note: host is Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit

Comment: Does VirtualBox support something like "raw usb" mapping? I didn't think so, but this question might be better on SuperUser

Comment: I have done this by installing openni http://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ZIr.png

but kinect still doesn't work

Comment: I have installed gust addtions ,mapped kinect usbs from virtual box settings and activated 3d directx accelerated

Answer (score -1):

There is no support for any virtualised platform when using the Kinect for Windows SDK.

Comment: When it will support? Is this in their future work? Thank you~

Comment: The October 2012 release of the Kinect for Windows SDK included support for VM's. I haven't tried VirtualBox but there should no longer be an issue with it: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/new.aspx